# Does AMQP 1.0 support in Service Bus works with proxy/Firewall?

Tags: servicebus

AMQP 1.0 support in Service Bus not working with Proxy. Enabled the proxy in the app.config with no luck.  Able to communicate with Servicebus thorugh proxy while accessing queues with Azure SDK.